# Spring Boot 1.3.5 scope session

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing a project with Spring Boot 1.3.5.
I want to add scope annotation to my bean.
I tried @Scope(value="session") and @SessionScoped.
But that can't solve my problem.

Bellow, is my file pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
  
  
  <groupId>SpringBootFirstApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>springbootfirstapp</artifactId>
 
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
 
  <packaging>war</packaging>
 
 

<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>prime-repo</id>
  <name>Prime Repo</name>
  <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
        <!-- can be 8 also -->
  <java.version>7</java.version>
    
        <!-- can be 8.0.x also -->
        <tomcat.version>7.0.62</tomcat.version>
        
        <jsf-mojarra.version>2.2.11</jsf-mojarra.version>
       
 </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  
 
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>      
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
  <artifactId>glass-x</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
 </dependency>
  
 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
   <version>${jsf-mojarra.version}</version>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  
</dependencies>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <!-- Eclipse: If Eclipse configured to refresh the workspace automatically,
                                  "mvn spring-boot:run" can fail in some rare cases.
                    -->
                    <addResources>false</addResources>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Have you please any idea how annotate a bean with session scope annotation when using Spring Boot 1.3.5 ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try that:

```html
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyBean implements ApplicationContextAware, Serializable
{
  ...
}
```

HTH

Comment: Yes that is it. Thanks for help @Saria